# Import tabular text data

Tags: import, list-manipulation, text

I have a text file created with a bash script I wanted to read the data avoiding the first line.

I have written few dirty codes, but I wondered if anybody can do it in fewest possible nice one liners. I'm trying to learn to code more efficiently.

Here is the table.

```
Compound        State       Method      Approach    S^2         Energy              Cube file       Path
CF2             triplet     CC          NONE        2.007614    -237.329191671337   plotted         ./3B1/CF2-CC-t.out
CF2             triplet     DFT         NONE        2.005408    -237.601091985298   plotted         ./3B1/CF2-t.out
```

I am looking for the nicest possible way to read all this table into a matrix `DATA[[x,y]]`

Comment: Look up [`Import` of TSV files](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/TSV.html) paying attention to the `"TextDelimiters"` option.

Comment: It may also be useful to you to add `"HeaderLines" -> 1` to your `Import` expression to avoid importing the first line. Alternatively you could use a construct like `Import[your arguments][[2;;]]` to discard that first line.

Comment: Thanks for the accept, but would be better for you and the community if you were to remove the accept and merely up-vote my answer. It is good idea not to accept answers for 24 to 48 hours after posting so as to encourage alternative answers. At the end of the 24 - 48 hour period, you should then accept the *best* answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the file containing the data has the extension ".tsv" and that you want to choose the file from a system file-open dialog (rather than type in the file name), it can be done with

```
data = 
   Module[{path}, 
     path = 
       SystemDialogInput["FileOpen", "*.tsv", WindowTitle -> "Select a TSV file"];
     If[path === $Canceled, $Canceled, Import[path, "HeaderLines" -> 1]]];
data
```

> ```
> {{"CF2", "triplet", "CC", "NONE", 2.00761, -237.329, "plotted", "./3B1/CF2-CC-t.out"}, 
>  {"CF2", "triplet", "DFT", "NONE", 2.00541, -237.601, "plotted", "./3B1/CF2-t.out"}}
> ```

If you don't want to be restricted to the extension ".tsv", use

```
data = 
   Module[{path}, 
     path = 
       SystemDialogInput["FileOpen", "*.*", WindowTitle -> "Select a data file"];
     If[path === $Canceled, $Canceled, Import[path, "TSV", "HeaderLines" -> 1]]];
```

But the file itself will still have to be a tab delimited file.